# Reactjs typescript disable linting for a specific folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, eslint

I use charting_library for a react/typescript project.
I am getting these compilation errors due to linting and CL suggests ignoring these linting issues.

[image]

This is my tsconfig.json file

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types":[
      "node",
      "webpack-env" // here
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "types/*.d.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have added a separate file called tsconfig.eslint.json and tried to put the folder path like this

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "exclude": ["./src/pages/instuments/technicalAnalysis/charting_library/*js"]
  }
```

But this doesn't exclude the folder. How do I exclude the charting_libray folder from linting?

Comment: Maybe try `./src/pages/instuments/technicalAnalysis/charting_library/*.js` or `./src/pages/instuments/technicalAnalysis/charting_library`

Comment: @captain-yossarian it's /*.js I update the question

Comment: No , you have `/*js` whereas it should be a dot `.` between `*` and `js` ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about that `tsconfig.eslint.json` file.

Since you want `eslint` to ignore that folder, you should create a `.eslintignore` in the root of your project.

In `.eslintignore` file, add/append this line:

```
src/pages/instuments/technicalAnalysis/charting_library/**/*.js
```

the `**/*.js` part matches all `.js` files in `charting_library` and subfolders of that folder.